# Need to search the word only in particular sheet with the given code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Example()
 Dim strFind As String
   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Dim rngFound As Range
   Dim CellNo As String
   Dim Data As String

   strFind = InputBox(prompt:="Enter string to find", Title:="Find what?")
   If Len(strFind) > 0 Then
      For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         Set rngFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(what:=strFind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
         If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto rngFound, True
              CellNo = rngFound.Address(Offset, Offset)
         End If
      Next wks
   '   MsgBox strFind & " not found."
   End If
End Sub
```

The above code is for search some word over the excel workbook and shows the word which it had find last.

Ex: If we have name "Cat" in Sheet 1 and in Sheet 2. So this code helps to show the Cat in sheet 2 only and not caring of sheet 1.

So now what i want to do is, i want to select the sheet. so it has to search only on that selected sheet.
If we ask it to take sheet1, it has to search the cat only from sheet 1. it should not go to sheet2 and further.

Note: It has to search according to sheet name. 
If we give the Sheet2, It has to search cat only on sheet 2. So sheet name is provided.

I have tried with couple of experiments, it is showing type mismatch, Object required.

Can any only help me the modifications in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this part of the code:

```
  'For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     Set rngFound = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(what:=strFind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
     If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto rngFound, True
          CellNo = rngFound.Address(Offset, Offset)
     End If
  'Next wks
```

You just need to remove the loop and change rngFound to look only in the ActiveSheet.

Comment: i Will give the sheet Name.. it has to search only on that particular sheet. :) Can you please help me.

Comment: @user3305322, change `ActiveSheet` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0):

Remove loop and change wks for needed value
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Comment: HI, Yup i have already gone through that site.
But what i require is, we will give the sheet name. it has to search only in that sheet according to sheet name..